# Laravel mix doesn't compile file as expected

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I have an issue with mix that I can't seem to fix.

I have a file in which I require several node modules and init a vue root component

`routes.js`

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
window._ = require('lodash');
window.axios = require('axios');

const root = new Vue({
    el: '#root'
});
```

In my mix file I define where the file should be compiled like so:
`mix.js('resources/assets/js/routes.js', 'public/assets/js');`

Everything compiles without any errors using `npm run dev` but when I open the compiled file the contents are not compiled at all! It's like the file wasn't run trough webpack and just copied.

The weird thing is that I use several other components on different pages that do compile like they should. I'm at a loss what the problem might be for this specific instance, since the way the file is built up and the mix directive in `webpack.mix.js` is exactly the same.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: package.json contents.

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^8.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.17",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "vue": "^2.5.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "awe-dnd": "^0.3.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "tinymce": "^4.7.6",
    "vue-l-carousel": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add the contents of your package.json? Maybe it has something to do with the versions

Comment: Hi @Reduxx thanks for your reply. I have just added the package.json contents. The weird thing is that compiling several other files does succeed while i'm not doing anything different at all as far as I can see

Comment: Did you do yarn install or npm install . I had the same problem when I did the yarn install but after removing the node_modules folder and doing the npm install and running npm run dev it worked for me

Comment: I just tried this with npm install and the same setup, worked like a charm. Though it's possible to be a yarn issue, will test this right now :) Edit: yarn also works and mix compiles through webpack. Can you maybe add your whole webpack.mix.js file?

Comment: Found it! We are using a dashboard template from envato which came with a predefined webpack.mix.js file. This file contained a rule to copy the entire resources/assets/js directory to the public dir. Somehow this caused the issue, not sure why but since everything is compiled we do not need to copy the whole thing over at all.

Thanks for getting us on the right track! :)